# Asp.net Webforms - How to Read a file Using Binary Reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-upload

I have a file which I upload to a temp folder after having done some image resizing as follows:

```
/uploads/temp/myfile.jpg
```

How can I read this file into a binary reader as follows if all I have is the file path as indicated above i.e. In the example below I get error:

```
Error in saving fileSystem.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\uploads\\temp\\myfile.jpg'

 var fs = new FileStream('/uploads/temp/myfile.jpg', FileMode.Open);
 using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
 {
      image.ImageContent = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
 }
```

Comment: You can store image in folder and store image address in database.

Comment: @Ali I already know how I can do that. My questions is about storing to a database.

Comment: Are you asking about how to load the image from the temp folder and store it into a database? If so, what kind of database are you using and how are you storing other data in the database?

Comment: @user2154065 Storing into a SQL Server DB. All I need to know is how to read the file from the temp folder and save into the database.

Comment: Open the file using FileStream or BinaryReader to read and then use SQL Server connection, command objects to write to database. Oh! Just saw you are using something which I am unfamiliar with. Please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix by doing the following:

```
 var fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/") + "/uploads/temp/myfile.jpg", FileMode.Open);
```